# how to see which users are executing a command (Shell Scripting)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I'm wondering if you could help me with this issue. 
I need to write a shell script to see if other users are executing a watch command in the same computer in which an x command is beeing executed.
Could you help me guys?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the question is possible to use `ps -aux | grep <prgname>` as root user.

E.G.: `ps -aux | grep firefox` executing this command (as root), it returns the following output:

```
sergio    3252 24.1  6.7 1840936 540264 ?      Sl   09:48 123:36 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
root     23059  0.0  0.0  15944   948 pts/7    S+   18:20   0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

The last line is the command I've executed!

Using ps a way to solve your problem may be to use a script like the following. I think that is possible to create better solutions, but this seems to run good on my Ubuntu 14.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
search="watch"

tmp=`mktemp`
ps -aux | tr -s ' ' | grep "$search" > $tmp

while read fileline
do
user=`echo $fileline | cut -f1 -d\  `
prg=`echo $fileline | cut -f11 -d\  `
prg=`basename $prg`
if [ $prg == $search ]; then
    echo "$user - $prg"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
fi
done < $tmp

if [ $i == 0 ]; then
    echo User not found
fi

rm $tmp
```

Comment: Hey Sergio I noticed you're italian (as me) :D. However i dont think this is the solution for my problem.  the code you wrote here shows only who's executing the watch command, right? but I Have to know those users that are executing the watch command in the same computer in which a MyOwnCommand is beeing executed. I'm not sure if I explained well. Can you help me? thank you

Comment: @Pino. Yes, I'm Italian :) ! Reading what you write I understand you want know who's the user executing your program using watch: IE:`watch -b MyOwnCommand`. Something like `ps -aux | grep "watch" | grep "MyOwnCommand"` might solve your issue! I suggest you to place this question also in [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: @Pino. ... elsewhere, If you need to know if watch and MyOwnCommand are executed simultaneously and independently you may use two ps: `ps -aux | grep "watch"` and `ps -aux | grep "MyOwnCommand"`

Comment: it doesn't work D: and i guess i didn't explained well. I have to discover if there are users that are executing the watch command in the same machine and in the same time of another running command...       (I send you the text on fb on other messages)

Comment: The "same" machine is clear is the machine where you run the script ...  I think!

Comment: and how can i use two ps? i mean.. can i see users that are running both of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78668/discussion-between-sergio-formiggini-and-pino).

Comment: @Pino. Last version is here! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    if [ -n "`ssh $hostname pgrep -f 'Pino_special_command'`" ]; then
        ssh $hostname "ps -aux | grep watch" | grep -v "grep"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) command

```
pgrep watch
```